# Cannot upvote discussions on Area51

Tags: support, bug, area-51, login, facebook

Whenever I am trying to upvote a discussion on Area 51, for example [this one](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11453/lets-not-let-it-get-closed-this-time) it tells me:

> Thanks for the feedback!
> This site is free and open to everyone, but our registered users get extra privileges like posting, commenting, and voting.

I click on the "Sign up using Facebook" button since all my other StackExchange accounts are connected to my Facebook account (just signed up for Math.SE today). When doing so, I appear at [a page that cannot be found](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/authenticate?returnurl=%2Fquestions%2F11453%2Flets-not-let-it-get-closed-this-time). But at the top I see a bar telling me to:

> Finish signing up by setting a password for your account

So I click the bar, once again I appear at a [choose your login method page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/authenticate?returnurl=%2Fquestions%2F11453%2Flets-not-let-it-get-closed-this-time). Choosing Facebook again and I get redirected to [the main Area51 site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/#_=_) where I navigate to a discussion again and try to upvote it, and the whole process starts over.

Seems like something about the login system is broken around here. Or is it just my account?

## Summary, to make things clear:

- I am aware that Discuss is effectively a meta site for Area 51
- The problem here is **not** about the 404 error
- **I am logged in on Area 51**
- I **can** upvote and downvote example questions, I have even posted an example question of my own a while ago
- I still **can't use Discuss**

Comment: Not a totally obvious duplicate, but discuss is *effectively* a meta site.

Comment: @Shog9 Honestly, marking this question as a duplicate doesn't help me with my problem **at all**. I am aware that discuss is effectively a meta site. **How on earth am I supposed to login?**

Comment: Oh, sorry - just log in on [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/login) and you should be logged into Discuss automatically.

Comment: @Shog9 Sorry for not mentioning it but **I am already logged in on Area51.** I can upvote and downvote example questions without any problems. **I still can't login on Discuss**

Comment: Hang on; your account was a little bit broken. Then I broke it worse. Should be all better in just a few seconds.

Comment: @Shog9 "your account was a little bit broken. Then I broke it worse." - Exactly the kind of thing you want to hear from a StackExchange moderator :)

Comment: Ok - you should be in good shape now. Let me know if you're not automatically logged in when you visit discuss.area51

Comment: @Shog9 Would you like to explain this statement to the world? So we can post the extended statment with the tag "-mod of Stack Overflow".

Comment: It's occasionally possible to end up with an unregistered *profile* on a registered *account*, @hichris123. The symptoms of this are the "finish signing up..." message coupled with an inability to actually log in / register. There are two different ways to fix this, depending on whether or not we're talking about a "child meta" account. I picked the wrong one at first.

Comment: @Shog9 That's more like it. Thanks. (Although this technically still isn't a duplicate) Your latest comments deserve to be flagged as "Not a comment, it's an answer"

Comment: eh; if that other bug hadn't existed, it'd have been a lot more obvious what was happening here.

Comment: I don't know [if my shape is any better](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12585002#12585002) but I can certainly use discuss now.